# How can I upload any other file types like .py , .obj,

Tags: feature-request

### Importing Another file formats not **.blend or img only**

I know that I can import a .blend or an image file but,how can I
Import other formats like .py , .obj , .dae .....

How can i make it in blender stack exchange ?

Comment: As far as `.py` goes, that can just be copy-pasted as a code block. `.obj` and `.dae` can be imported in to a `.blend` and uploaded, but that won't always work for every question.

Comment: If you're thinking to upload another file format by itself, chances are your question probably isn't Blender exclusive, if not, it should be fine to embed it into one and outline the problem you're having with said file in *Blender* in a project context.